# Use asset pipeline in a rails haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I Have a haml file with some meta definitions.
I need to define the facebook image metatag like

```
<meta property="og:image" content="path-to/mylogo.png" />
```

How can I do that with asset pipeline, I have tried to do the following

```
%meta(property="og:image", content=image_url('newLogo.png'))
```

but it gives me an error.

Comment: try this: `%meta{content: image_url('newLogo.png'), property: "og:image"}`

Answer (score 1):

You are not using proper syntax

```
%meta{ property: "og:image", content: image_url('newLogo.png')}/
```

And for future reference you can use this online tool to convert html to haml - [**`htmltohaml.com`**](http://htmltohaml.com/)